# What is the use of Aerospike DataCenter and cluster nodes ? any Difference between them?

Tags: datastore, aerospike

I’m setting up aerospike Db, I want to store data with replication.
I'm new to this Db.

what to use ? either cluster nodes?  or data centers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Data center** is just a reference to location where you have servers running. On each server, in production, you will run one instance of Aerospike called a "**node**". You can then configure many nodes to form an Aerospike **cluster**.  If you use servers on AWS, then which ever region and zone you are creating your instances can be referred to as the "data center". Aerospike also offers an optional feature called cross-datacenter replication or **XDR**. XDR will allow you to move data between two Aerospike clusters, typically each cluster in a different datacenter, most users have their datacenters geographically separate. So, XDR is for moving data between two or more separate Aerospike clusters.